# Openedx cms redirect to a domain instead of IP

Tags: openedx

I want to add openedx cms studio link (currently as `http://ipaddress:18010`) to somedomain/edx-studio
I have updated

- httpd-vhosts.conf file
- httpd-app.conf
- edx_virtualhosts.conf
- cms.env.json

nothing works. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The regular approach for this is to use a subdomain for studio. So your final setup looks like `https://studio.yourdomain.com`

If you are using ansible (recommended), the way to go is to set `EDXAPP_CMS_NGINX_PORT: 80` on your `server_vars.yml` file and run ansible again.

If you are doing the changes manually (not recommended at all) you would have to change `/edx/app/nginx/sites-available/cms` to make it listen on port 80 instead of 18010. Normally the `server_name` is set to `~^((stage|prod)-)?studio.*` which aleady works but you can change it there.

The manual change is not recomended since running ansible in the future will override you manual changes with whatever ansible has in its variables.